# How can show frame photo on Target images and screenshot it?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, game-engine, vuforia

I am a new developer with Unity Vuforia and now I work with project AR. I don't know why can I archive my goal. The flow of the application is that when user scan the vuforia Target image, the frame photo will show up. The difficulty is that the frame photo can show on my device screen, that's why I can't screenshot the image. You can look on my images that attached to know clearly.
If all of you know the way to do it, please feel free to tell me. 
Thank you for your good reply.

[image]

[image]

[image]